# Maximum weighted antichain over a DAG with cardinality constraint

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, dag

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a vertex weighted DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph), with positive real valued weights.

Let also $k\leq \left\vert V\right\vert$, is there any way to find a maximum weighted antichain over $G$ (a set of vertexes $A\subseteq V$ where there is no edges between elements of $A$) , with cardinality less or equal than $k$?

The unconstrained problem (i.e. where the size of the anti-chain is not bounded) can be solved by reducing it to a minumum flow problem (as can be seen in this [Technical Report by Cong](http://fmdb.cs.ucla.edu/Treports/930014.pdf)).

Is this problem NP-hard?